# Interpreting glm() function with interaction effect

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I have a dataset with 10 variables. Some are continuous, some binary. I'm trying to work out the interaction effect of 2 variables A (binary) and B (binary) on C (binary). I'm confused as to how I should code this in R.

```
logit1 <- glm(C ~ ., data = myData, family = "binomial"(link=logit))

logit2 <- glm(C ~ . + .:., data = myData, family = "binomial"(link=logit))

logit3 <- glm(C ~ . + A:B, data = myData, family = "binomial"(link=logit))

logit4 <- glm(C ~ . + A:., data = myData, family = "binomial"(link=logit))
```

I get different results for each one.

Comment: The pure coding is off-topic here. However, there's a statistical question, too. What model do you want? I assume $A+B+K+D+E+F+G+H+I+J + AB = C$, but it isn't obvious.

Comment: @Dave Let's say I only want to explore the interaction between A and B, do I need to code for the interaction effect between A and all the other variables too? Or can I just simply code for the interaction between A and B?